# Some Firebase security rules apply for admin in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-admin, google-cloud-functions

Cloud Function gets a firebase permission denied error when updating or removing.

The service account is initialized with credentials from a file in order to use `auth.createCustomToken` which isn't currently available for the default account

```
admin = require('firebase-admin');
functions = require('firebase-functions');
credential = admin.credential.cert(require('./credentials.json'));
admin.initializeApp({credential: credential, databaseURL: functions.config().firebase.databaseURL});
```

The security rules that prevent the updates:

```
"downloads": {
  "$key": {
    ".write": "data.val() == null"
  }
}
```

The user inserts data with `push` into `/downloads` then Cloud Function tries to update and subsequently remove. Both of these operations fail even though admin accounts supposedly bypass all security rules including validation.

```
FIREBASE WARNING: update at /downloads/-Kexz33ljYjKblF_ZgUo failed: permission_denied
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /downloads/-Kexz33ljYjKblF_ZgUo failed: permission_denied
```

The first error (update) disappears if I change the rules to this:

```
"downloads": {
  "$key": {
    ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

#### UPDATE

The workaround is to redefine `event.data.ref` to be

```
ref = admin.database().ref(event.data.ref.path.toString())
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that triggers the `permission_denied`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within the [`event.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#data) object returned to your Cloud Function's `onWrite()` callback, there are two types of Database references: one that is scoped to to the same permissions as the user who triggered the write ([`event.data.ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#ref)) and one that is scoped with admin rights, granting full read and write access ([`event.data.adminRef`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#adminRef)). I can't tell since you didn't provide a code sample showing your Cloud Function, but I bet you are using `event.data.ref`. Switching to use `event.data.adminRef` should resolve your problem.